# Проблема с драйверами видеокарты

Tags: драйвер, amd

Решил я обновить драйвера на видеокарту Radeon tm RX550, скачал драйвера с оф сайта, версии 21.11.1, после перезагрузки кс го не запускаеться, во всех других играх 1 фпс, а также видеокарта переиминовалась в базовый видеоадаптер (майкрасофт), попробовал откатиться но не могу

Comment: Скорее всего, в процессе что-то пошло не так, при этом установщик успел удалить предыдущую версию драйвера. Попробуйте ещё раз установить

Comment: Переустановил драйвера, не помогло, поставил другую версию драйверов, не помогло, скачал программу от амд которая сама поставит лучшие драйвера, не помогло